# How to compare the rows of two certain elements?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a validation which searches every row of the clientDocument and see if it's changed by comparing the same row in the serverDocument. The comparing thing I made now compares the whole documents.

```js
JSON.stringify(clientDocument.scheduledLines) != JSON.stringify(serverDocument.scheduledLines)
```

data samples.

```
// clientDocument: scheduledLines
[
    {
      _id: '6604',
      resourceId: '5b482',
      workOrderId: 'muoj'
    },
    {
     _id: '9431',
      resourceId: '9w214',
      workOrderId: 'wocs'
    }
  ]

// serverDocument: scheduledLines
[
    {
      _id: '6604',
      resourceId: '5b482',
      workOrderId: 'muoj'
    },
    {
     _id: '9431',
      resourceId: '9w214',
      workOrderId: 'eiws'
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

the code below, result array have 2 types

1. rows in first array that not exist `_id` in second array,
2. rows in first array that exist `_id` in second array but different objects

```js
let t1 = [
    {
      _id: '6604',
      resourceId: '5b482',
      workOrderId: 'muoj',
    },
    {
     _id: '9431',
      resourceId: '9w214',
      workOrderId: 'wocs', 
    }
  ]

let t2 = [
    {
      _id: '6604',
      resourceId: '5b482',
      workOrderId: 'muoj',
    },
    {
     _id: '9431',
      resourceId: '9w214',
      workOrderId: 'eiws', 
    }
  ]

let result = t1.filter((itm1)=>{
    let _id1 = itm1._id;
    return !t2.some((itm2)=>{
        let _id2 = itm2._id;
        return JSON.stringify(itm1) === JSON.stringify(itm2)
    })
})
```